# Running clone n number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm currently using this code to clone a text input field when clicking on a button with the id btnAdd

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

                if (newNum == 25)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });
```

What i want to do is be able to press another button and have it add a certain number of cloned text fields, while still renaming the ids to name + n

I want to do this so i can have a button create fx. 5 text fields and then populate them with predetermined values.

Right now i have to first create 4 textfields for 5 total, and then call the function with another button, to alter the text fields.

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

---

Example i used in comments:

Let’s say that i want to have a site where you can input a list of names

I start with one input boxes

```
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="Port" />
</div>
```

Then i want the user to be able to add more input boxes. so i use the clone code in the OP

This enables the user to manually add all the names they want.

But i want to be able to have the user be able to choose from pre selected lists, lets say a list of all the names of the football team.

So i want the user to be able to press a button, which creates fx. 11 input boxes, and then fills out the boxes with all the 11 names of the football team.
 To do this i have been using this code:

```
function Input() {
                $('#name1').val(‘John’)
                $('#name2').val(’Steve’)
                $('#name3').val(‘Maria’)
                $('#name4').val(‘Ida’)
            }
```

But if the user has not created enough clones of the input boxes, this just fills out the created ones.

Comment: Could you make code snippet with the code you have now? I am not totally understanding what you want to achieve. Any examples?

Comment: Let’s say that i want to have a site where you can input a list of names

I start with one input boxes

`<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="Port" />
</div>`

Then i want the user to be able to add more input boxes. so i use the clone code in the OP

This enables the user to manually add all the names they want.

Comment: But i want to be able to have the user be able to choose from pre selected lists, lets say a list of all the names of the football team

So i want the user to be able to press a button, which creates fx. 11 input boxes, and then fills out the boxes with all the names of the football team.
 To do this i have been using this code:
`function Input() {
          $('#name1').val(‘John’)
          $('#name2').val(’Steve’)
          $('#name3').val(‘Maria’)
          $('#name4').val(‘Ida’)
      }`
But if the user has not created enough clones of the input boxes, this just fills out the created ones.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the behaviour you wanted. It basically adds inputs in the div block you want with some random names as value.

```js
var names = ["Chris", "Jimmy", "George", "Martin", "Keith"];

function createInputs(numberOfInputs, blockId) {
  var i = 0;
  var inputBlock = $("#" + blockId);
  
  inputBlock.empty();
  
  while(i < numberOfInputs && i < names.length) {
    inputBlock.append($('<input type="text" name="name" id="name'+ i + '"/>').val(names[i]));
    i++;
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="createInputs(3, 'input1')">Create 3 random inputs</button>
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="Port" />
</div>

<button onclick="createInputs(5, 'input2')">Create 5 random inputs</button>
<div id="input2" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="Port" />
</div>
```